# Creating vec with auxiliary memory after declaration with Armadillo c++

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am using the the armadillo matrix library in c++, and I want to create a vec that uses "auxiliare memory". The standard way to do this is

```
vec qq(6); qq<<1<<2<<3<<4<<5<<6;
double *qqd = qq.memptr();
vec b1(qqd, 6, false);
```

So here, if I change the elements in b1, the elements in qq is changed, which is what I want. However, in my program, I declare the `b1` vector globaly, so when I define it, I cant call the constructor that makes `b1` use "auxiliare memory". Is there a function in armadillo that does what I want? Why do I get different results when I run the codes below?

```
vec b1= vec(qq.memptr(), 3, false); //changing  b1 element changes one of qq's element

vec b1;
b1= vec(qq.memptr(), 3, false); //changing b1 element does not chagne qq's
```

So, how can I make a vector use the memory from a other vector, when it is declared globaly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using global variables is generally a [bad idea](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

However if you insist on using them, here is one possible way of using auxiliary memory with global Armadillo vectors:

```
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;

vec* x;   // global declaration as a pointer; points to garbage by default

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  double data[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

  // create vector x and make it use the data array
  x = new vec(data, 4, false);  

  vec& y = (*x);  // use y as an "easier to use" alias of x

  y.print("y:");

  // as x is a pointer pointing to an instance of the vec class,
  // we need to delete the memory used by the vec class before exiting
  // (this doesn't touch the data array, as it's external to the vector)

  delete x;

  return 0;
  }
```